# AWS Lambda Logs to One JSON Line

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, elastic-stack, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have small Python code executing in AWS lambda,
but Lambda puts the logs to CloudWatch Logs in a very inconvenient format:
[image]

I want to send those logs to ELK for visualization. Is there a way to put all Lambda iteration logs to one json file?

Answer (score 10):

The preloaded `LambdaLoggerHandler` uses the standard class `logging.Formatter`.
Source: https://www.denialof.services/lambda/

Replace the formatter by a custom class that outputs to JSON.
Also the `extra` dict could contains additionnals values, `extra['data']` avoids conflicts with others logrecord properties.

```py
import logging
import json

class FormatterJSON(logging.Formatter):
    def format(self, record):
        record.message = record.getMessage()
        if self.usesTime():
            record.asctime = self.formatTime(record, self.datefmt)
        j = {
            'levelname': record.levelname,
            'time': '%(asctime)s.%(msecs)dZ' % dict(asctime=record.asctime, msecs=record.msecs),
            'aws_request_id': getattr(record, 'aws_request_id', '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'),
            'message': record.message,
            'module': record.module,
            'extra_data': record.__dict__.get('data', {}),
        }
        return json.dumps(j)


logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel('INFO')

formatter = FormatterJSON(
    '[%(levelname)s]\t%(asctime)s.%(msecs)dZ\t%(levelno)s\t%(message)s\n',
    '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'
)
# Replace the LambdaLoggerHandler formatter :
logger.handlers[0].setFormatter(formatter)


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    my_input = {
        'key1': 'value1',
        'key2': 'value2'
    }
    logger.info('Process Info: %s', 'Hello', extra=dict(data=my_input))
```

However any stacktraces keeps render as usual.

Then CloudWatch gets this :

```
{
    "levelname": "INFO",
    "time": "2018-12-13T11:35:24.130Z",
    "aws_request_id": "2e0f7055-fecb-11e8-8376-b77695872964",
    "message": "Process Info: Hello",
    "module": "lambda_function",
    "extra_data": {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to write your logs in the following way:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

def my_logging_handler(event, context):
    logger.error(
        json.dumps(
            {
                'key1': 'value1',
                'key2': 'value2'
            }
        )
    )
    return 'Hello from Lambda!'
```

Answer (score 1):

You should set your application to log as JSON. This way you can log all info as a single JSON line. This will also make it much easier to analyse downstream in ELK.

For example you can use [Watchtower](https://watchtower.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```
import watchtower, logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.addHandler(watchtower.CloudWatchLogHandler())
logger.info("Hi")
logger.info(dict(foo="bar", details={}))
```

This won't include the START and END lines, but you can always have your application add that information if needed.

Answer (score 0):

In short, there is not a way to force all logs to go to one log stream.  They all should be in the same log group though.  Lambda creates a new log stream whenever a new version is deployed or whenever a new instance of a lambda is spun up.  You have a couple of options when it comes to getting this data into ELK.

1. You could investegate the [Cloudwatch Logstash Plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-cloudwatch.html).  I've never used it so I can't vouch for it's ease and/or effectiveness.
2. You can wire up [Cloudwatch Logs as a trigger](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invoking-lambda-function.html#supported-event-source-cloudwatch-logs) to another lambda that does processing.
3. Cloudwatch provides a pretty powerful search.  You could periodically query the data from Cloudwatch and post it to your Logstash.
4. Would be to manually post this data to a Logstash server instead of logging it to Cloudwatch.

Comment: > 1. *plugins-inputs-cloudwatch* only retrieves metrics.

For logs, a third party plugin such as [logstash-input-cloudwatch-logs](https://github.com/lukewaite/logstash-input-cloudwatch-logs) could do the job.